# Removing panels from an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, loops, for-loop

I have created a 10 by 10 array of Jpanels and I have to remove a square from them. The square that is clicked must be removed and so do all of the squares below it and to the right of it.
currently, when I click a square it only deletes one square.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1hx1.jpg - this is what the grid looks like and then the desired outcome.
Attached below is the code I am currently using. any help is welcome. Please let me know if I need to attach any more code, thank you.

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        playingGrid[x] = new JPanel[10];
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            playingGrid[x][y] = new JPanel();
            playingGrid[x][y]= new ImagePanel(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                                  .getImage("rock.jpg"));   
            pcenter.add(playingGrid[x][y]);
            playingGrid[x][y].addMouseListener(new Rockbreaker());
        }

    }
    f.getContentPane().add(pcenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
public class Rockbreaker implements MouseListener{

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         //sets all columns greater than one clicked to invisible 
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                if(playingGrid[x][y]== e.getSource()){                  
                        for (int c=0;c<100;c++){
                            if(c>x){
                                playingGrid[x][y].setVisible(false);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: I've deleted your JavaScript tag as your question has nothing to do with this language and have added the Swing tag as your question has all to do with this library. But as to your actual question, maybe it's me, but I don't have a clue as to what you're trying to do or what problem you're having in your attempt. If you don't get a decent answer soon, please seriously consider improving this question, including posting more relevant and well explained details and a [mcve] compliant code post.

Comment: Also, why do you assign a new JPanel to your grid, `playingGrid[x][y]`, and then immediately discard this JPanel object and assign a completely different object, an ImagePanel to the same grid location? It makes no sense.

Comment: Also, if this were my project, I probably wouldn't change the visibility of the JPanels in my grid, as this could mess up the layout of all the visible components in the grid, but instead would likely use a grid of JLabel and would simply swap the Icons that the labels displayed.

Comment: Hey thanks hovercraft for all these tips, sorry if my formatting of question etc sucked trying to get used to this site, i have fixed the problem now. thanks for taking the time:)

Comment: *".. i have fixed the problem now."* The problem of 'no MCVE' is still evident..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a flaw on your logic. I'm not sure what you were trying to do in the if (c>x) block, but you could easily rewrite it to

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int selectedX = -1;
    int selectedY = -1;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            if(playingGrid[x][y]== e.getSource()){
                playingGrid[x][y].setVisible(false);
                selectedX = x;
                selectedY = y;
            } else if (selectedX > 0 && selectedY > 0 && selectedX <= x && selectedY <= y) {
                playingGrid[x][y].setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```